# Function returns string and want to show it inside nav bar

Tags: php

I have a function called "login_status()" it has another function inside of it to check if the user is logged in or not and return text based on the login status:

```
 function login_status() {
        if (logged_in()) {
            echo $log_status = "Sign Out";
        }
        else {
            echo $log_status = "Sign In";
        }
    }
```

The function is inside a file and that file is included on all pages.
How can i show the function returned string "Sign Out" or "Sign In" inside my nav bar in all of my pages?

My nav bar code is inside a file called header.php and included on all pages just like the footer.

The function is working, I only need to know how to show the echoed text inside of my nav bar.

Comment: Maybe you should actually *`return`* the value instead of `echo`ing it?

Comment: At first you may show us what exactly do you mean by 'navbar' and what it exactly is?

Comment: I want to show in the navigation bar a button (sign in) or (sign out) with a correct link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `return` instead of `echo` in function

```
function login_status() 
{
    if (logged_in()) {
        $log_status = "Sign Out";
    }
    else {
        $log_status = "Sign In";
    }
    return $log_status;
}
```

and get it:

```
<div>
    <?php echo login_status(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You answer is great, I want to know from you what makes my code not very good? is it because i have another function used inside called logged_in()? should i use this function to get the return value for better code and shorter? people here think that all users are professional programmers.

Comment: Your function is great i think because of it is shortener. You can use this function from everywhere. Just you need return with user value like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You could use output buffering and capture the `echo` calls:

```
ob_start();
login_status();
$o = ob_get_clean();
if ($o === "Sign In") {
    // signed in
}
```

Or, you could write *good* code ;)

Output buffering works here, but this is of course not very good software design.